# Data exchange via Intent between Fragments works on pre-5.0 but not on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

As a part of The Big Nerd Ranch's Android Guide example Criminal Intent,
I am updating a button with date/time entered in the
Date/TimePicker. Button and Date/TimePicker reside in different
fragments. I am transferring data between them using an Intent. It
works fine on Pre-Lollipop devices but doesn't seem to update button
text on Android 5.0 or Lollipop devices. What am I missing?

Full code can be seen at [Github](https://github.com/donniezazen/The-Big-Nerd-Ranch-Guide/tree/master/CriminalIntent).

**CrimeFragment.java**

```
package com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitleField;
    private Button mDateButton;
    private Button mTimeButton;
    private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
    private static final String TAG = "CriminalFragment";
    public static final String EXTRA_CRIME_ID = "com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent.crime_id";
    private static final String DIALOG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String DIALOG_TIME = "time";
    private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_TIME = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);
        mCrime = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrime(crimeId);
    }

    private void updateDateAndTime() {
        Date d = mCrime.getDate();
        CharSequence c = DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy", d);
        CharSequence t = DateFormat.format("h:mm a", d);
        mDateButton.setText(c);
        mTimeButton.setText(t);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

        mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // This space intentionally left blank
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable c) {
                // This one too
            }
        });

        mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment
                        .newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_DATE);
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_DATE);
            }
        });

        mTimeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_time);
        mTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                TimePickerFragment dialog = TimePickerFragment
                        .newInstance(mCrime.getDate());
                dialog.setTargetFragment(CrimeFragment.this, REQUEST_TIME);
                dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_TIME);
            }
        });

        updateDateAndTime();

        mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
        mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
        mSolvedCheckBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // Set the crime's solved property
                        mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
                    }
                });
        return v;
    }

    public static CrimeFragment newInstance(UUID crimeId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CRIME_ID, crimeId);

        CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATE) {
            Date date = (Date) data
                    .getSerializableExtra(DatePickerFragment.EXTRA_DATE);
            mCrime.setDate(date);
            updateDateAndTime();
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TIME) {
            Date date = (Date) data
                    .getSerializableExtra(TimePickerFragment.EXTRA_TIME);
            mCrime.setDate(date);
            updateDateAndTime();
        }
    }
}
```

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
package com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.sudhirkhanger.android.criminalintent.date";
    private Date mDate;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(),
                resultCode, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDate = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);
        // Create a Calendar to get the year, month, and day
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // calendar.setTime(mDate);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_date, null);

        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v
                .findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_datePicker);
        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
                    int day) {
                // Translate year, month, day into a Date object using a
                // calendar
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute)
                        .getTime();
                // Update argument to preserve selected value on rotation
                getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, mDate);
            }
        });

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                            }
                        }).create();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the communication between the Fragments, it's that for some reason the default CalendarView DatePicker in Lollipop never calls the OnDateChanged() method, so mDate in DatePickerFragment.java never gets changed; DatePickerFragment sends back to CrimeFragment the same value it received from CrimeFragment, so it only looks like the communication between the two Fragments isn't working.

The Lollipop DatePicker does call OnDateChanged() when it's in SpinnerView mode, so CrimeFragment's date will then get properly updated. Unfortunately, Lollipop ignores the android:calendarViewShown="false" directive in the DatePicker's tag in the dialog_date.xml file. The only way to force the DatePicker to display as spinners is to include a android:datePickerMode="spinner" directive in the DatePicker's xml tag. You will get a warning that this directive is supported in API 21 only, but it will be ignored by devices running pre-5.0 Android.You have to keep the calendarViewShown="false" directive for pre-5.0 devices.

DatePickerDialog appears to have been fixed in Android 5.0, so you could also use that resource in DatePickerFragment to make things work.